# Writing a custom wizard that copies files from the Nuget packages folder into a template

Tags: .net, templates, c#-4.0, wizard, nuget

If you look at the .NET MVC class, JQuery and other files are added to the newly created project from the template when create a new MVC project. I need to do something similar. I've studied this blog post: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/06/06/creating-a-custom-asp-net-mvc-project-template.aspx and attempted to do what is advised, however, the blog post warns: The package must exist in the %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Packages folder. This isn't a possibility for my application, so I think I need to write my own custom wizard that adds files and references to my project based on a path to packages. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be able to do this in NuGet 1.5. For more information see this blog post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/07/08/project-templates-and-preinstalled-nuget-packages.aspx